# Privoxy - Annoying Error Used IPTables

Tags: iptables, proxy, privoxy, hostapd

I'm running privoxy off a machine that also has hostapd installed, I am trying to run all http traffic from hostapd through privoxy i have already tried this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8118
```

but it gives errors accessing every http site that there is **Invalid Header Received By Client** this is not site specific, happens on all HTTP website (not https as privoxy can't handle that AFAIK, if it can please tell me.)

Anyway I would like to know how I can route all the traffic from wlan0 (what hostapd is on) to privoxy then to eth0 or atleast someway that means clients HAVE to go through privoxy.

Comment: Why don't you just null-route all traffic and then force people to use your filter as a proxy?  That protocol should be more suitable.